# Why does this print the last line? (SplFileObject)

Tags: php, spl, splfileobject

```
$file1 = new \SplFileObject('some file');
while( !$file1->eof() ){
    $data = $file1->fgets();
    if( !$file1->eof() ){
       echo $data;
    }
}
```

Doesn't fgets() step to the next line in the file? If so why does the file still pass the second !$file1->eof() statement? This occurs with ->valid() also.

Comment: see https://3v4l.org/clqTE - what output would you expect?

Comment: That's what I expect, but the file I keep trying this on still run the last line. Here is the files in question: ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/nasdaqlisted.txt

Comment: There's a linebreak after `File Creation Time: 1224201521:32|||||` (actually 0x0d 0x0A). fgets() stops reading _exactly_ there. But eof() tests wether the file pointer is at the EOF position which is figuratively speaking one position behind that last read operation. The next call to fgets() (and subsequently read()) will return 0 bytes and _then_ the file handle/stream is at the EOF position.

Comment: Man, I should've checked that. No idea why I didn't think of that, been tearing my hairs out. Throw that up as the answer to this if you could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[feof](http://docs.php.net/feof)/[SplFileObject::eof](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.eof.php) test whether the file handle/stream is at the EOF position.
Your source file has a linebreak after the last data line and fgets() stops right there. But the EOF position is figuratively speaking one position after that last read operation. SO the next fgets() (and subsequently read()) will return 0 bytes and only *then* the file is at the EOF position and feof() will return true.
In your concrete example (nasdaqlisted.txt) it might be sufficient to just test if $data is ==='' instead of $file1->eof() as there seem to be no other emtpy lines in that file.

Answer (score -2):

You're overriding `$data` each time loop runs. Try this:
`$data .= $file1->fgets();`